# Why does a NSView keeps on receiving touch events after the cursor has left its frame?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an NSView with `[self setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES];`

After the cursor has left the NSView frame, this methods keeps on being called, until I click/begin a new gesture, I don't really understand when it stops.

```
-(void)touchesMovedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self doStuffs:theEvent];
}
```

with coordinates expressed in other windows coordinate systems.

Is there a way do prevent this, or convert the coordinates back the view coordinates system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSResponder's `touchesMovedWithEvent` is called for touch events that start in your view, until they end (no matter if that's in your own view or elsewhere).

The event location is expressed in window coordinates. Converting to your view's coordinate system is easy:

```
- (void)touchesMovedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSPoint locInWindow;
    NSPoint locInView;

    locInWindow = [event locationInWindow];
    locInView = [self convertPoint:locInWindow fromView:nil];

    NSLog(@"Location in window: %@", NSStringFromPoint(locInWindow));
    NSLog(@"Location in view: %@", NSStringFromPoint(locInView));
}
```

If you want to handle raw touches for your own multitouch gestures, this is likely not enough info. You'll want to use `[event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseMoved inView:self]`, `normalizedPosition`, `deviceSize` etc. (see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html)).

Comment: Does the NSEvent contains a pointer to the window that generated the event ?

Comment: All non-periodic events contain a pointer to the window associated with the event (-[NSEvent window]). If you want to check if the current event's location is within or outside your window (or view), you can use NSPointInRect() with the event's location.

Comment: I actually meant NSView instead of window - but the window pointer is certainly enough.